How to process a large text file concurrently in .NET 8?
I have a text file with hundreds of thousands of lines in it and each line has fixed no. of properties delimited by a pipe (|).
I have processed each line as below:

Read a line from the file using StreamReader.ReadLineAsync().
Split the elements & populate them into a DTO.
Do some processing with the DTO.
If passed, make a couple of AWS S3 API calls, for each line / DTO.
If the Step 3 & 4 are passed then insert a row in PostgreSQL table A.
If the Step 3 & 4 are failed then insert a row in PostgreSQL table B.

I have implemented the above process in sequence, line by line, using C#, .NET 8 and Dapper (for PostgreSQL 16) successfully and implemented as a BackgroundService.
However, in order to reduce the execution time, is it suggested to use System.Threading.Channels to process a line as soon as it is read?
And for every 100 / 1000 lines, execute a bulk insert / copy statement into the database.
Any better recommendations or approaches please?
Edit: AWS calls are async and PostgreSQL calls are synchronous. It took approximately 5 minutes to execute 52 lines to process line by line. There are no limits to AWS S3 API calls.

Check NuGet for a CSV parser, which can usually be configured to handle alternative delimiters like a pipe (|). The good ones are also well-optimized for large sets out of the box.

Regarding the AWS calls and the PostgreSQL calls, are they synchronous or asynchronous? Also have you identified which step in the sequence is the bottleneck? Which takes more time to complete? Could you share any specific metrics?

Is there any limitation regarding concurrent calls to the AWS S3 API? Does the provider impose any limits on how many calls can be concurrently in flight?

You don't need to have producer/consumer pattern implementation, which is done with Channels in .NET.
You can simply define entire processing of a single line in separate async method and execute this method for each line. The key here is not to await the task, just start the work and read another line, start the task, read line, etc.
For that, you would need to have something to keep track of ongoing work (started Tasks), for example ConcurrentBag<Task>.
Last but not least, I have added SemaphoreSlim in order to not allow (possibly) hundred of thousands of Tasks to be spawned, which could lead to ThreadPool Starvation
Something like this:
// Specify appropriate value to limit concurrent processing.
private const byte MaxConcurrentExecutions = 10;
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new (MaxConcurrentExecutions);
private readonly List<Task> _tasks = new();

public async Task HeavyProcessingOfTheFileAsync()
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        // Wait for semaphore to let in.
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        _tasks.Add(ProcessLineAsync(line));
    }
}

// Consider implementing IAsyncDisposable to easily await Tasks and dispose of them appropriately.
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
}

private async Task ProcessLineAsync(string line)
{
    try
    {
        // ...generate DTO, save it in DB, whatever
    }
    finally
    {
        // Each task must release semaphore
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}


Maybe it's just me but i really don't like this. Assuming the processing tasks will run significantly longer than it takes to deserialize one item this probably will saturate the thread pool, won't it? (Did not DV, though)

@Fildor if done right, there are no threads.

@rory.ap yes there are. OP clearly states it is cpu-bound. Db-IO is only the last step. How would you force this into a no-thread situation?

@Fildor Added SemaphoreSlim to alleviate that. Thanks for spotting! :)

The await _semaphore.WaitAsync(); is usually positioned before entering the try block. Also why are you storing the tasks in a ConcurrentBag<T> instead of a List<T>?

@TheodorZoulias Corrected, i thought about thread safety at first, but there will be single thread writing to the colleciton :)

Right now your semaphore has no effect. You should only release the semaphore when ProcessLineAsync completes, not immediately after you started it. Also creating tasks doesn't necessarily starve threads. Though you might still want to use a Channel to aggregate results so they can be inserted into the database in batches.

@JeremyLakeman Right, I moved releasing semaphore :) good catch.

The ContinueWith continuation is going to suppress any exception thrown by the ProcessLineAsync, and also violates the CA2008 guideline.

@TheodorZoulias Corrected

Now it's OK. But essentially you have created an inferior version of Parallel.ForEachAsync. In case of an error it's won't terminate responsively.

I am assuming that the most expensive operation is the call to the AWS API. Inserting records in a local database typically requires a few milliseconds at most. So I don't think that optimizing the database operations (by buffering and bulk-inserting) will have any significant positive impact on the performance. My suggestion is to use not a Channel<T>, but the .NET 6 API Parallel.ForEachAsync. This API is well suited for parallelizing a mixture of synchronous and asynchronous operations, and is significantly simpler than implementing the producer-consumer pattern. Here is an example:
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 // Configurable
};

IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(lines, parallelOptions, async (line, ct) =>
{
    DTO dto = Parse(line);
    Process(dto);
    var result = await Aws.Call(dto, ct);
    if (result.Success)
        DB.InsertA(dto);
    else
        DB.InsertB(dto);
});

The ct is a CancellationToken that you can pass to any APIs that accepts one, to optimize the responsiveness in case of an error.
Instead of passing directly the lines to the Parallel.ForEachAsync, you could also consider parsing the strings to DTOs in an earlier stage, and passing instead an IEnumerable<DTO> or IAsyncEnumerable<DTO>. There is no particular advantage in doing so, but if you find it compelling for some reason, there is an example here (the Iterator method).
